# TranstionToRoute dose not hook the model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a function in controller that check if something is ok change the route with transtionToRoute

At first i create a new record with Local Storage Adapter and then i want to change the route :

```
 var i = this.store.createRecord('axisModel', {
            id: Math.random().toString(32).slice(2).substr(0, 5), //random ID generator
            uniqueName: item.uniqueName,
            name: item.name,
            hierarchyUniqueName: item.hierarchyUniqueName,
            type: 'filter',
            isMeasure: item.isMeasure,
            orderId: "",
            isActive: true
        });
        i.save();
this.transitionToRoute('filters', item);
```

the filters route code is something like this :

```
App.FiltersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model:function(params){
    console.log('here');
    return this.store.find('axisModel',params.filters_id);
}
});
```

but when the route change i cant see 'here' of console.log() and also i get this error :

```
Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

Comment: where does `item` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are using the `each` view helper in your `filters` template and referencing a model, but it's an object not an array:

```
{{#each}} ...
```

or

```
{{#each model}} ...
```

so you will receive this error, because the view helper will try to add observers to updated the ui when the array changes. But ember objects doesn't have a `addArrayObserver` method, and this error will be throwed.

You can remove the each, or if you expect more than one result, use the `store.filter`:

```
this.store.filter('axisModel', function(model) {
  model.get('someProperty') == otherProperty;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query for an array of records, the second parameter to `find` should be an object with the query params e.g.

```
model: function(params) {
  return this.store.find('axisModel', { filter: params.filters_id });
}
```

Since you are just passing an ID, you will query for a single record (with that ID) and your generated controller will be an ObjectController (instead of ArrayController) which doesn't work with `#each`.

Answer (score 0):

When you transition to a route internally, from within your Ember app, using either `link-to`, `transitionTo`, or `transitionToRoute` the `model` hook is skipped.  Ember expects you to pass the model that you want to use into the route at the time of the transition.  That's why you're not seeing the `console.log` statement like you expect.

Another possible problem is that when you call this :

```
this.transitionToRoute('filters', item)
```

You're providing a single item as the `model` for the `'filters'` route.  But if you were to hit reload, and get the `model` hook to fire, then you're returning a collection by using:

```
this.store.find('axisModel',params.filters_id)
```